# Regex in bash accepting only when typing the argument, but not when copy-pasting it

Tags: regex, bash

I wrote a little helper function to my bash script to validate a ticket number that the user entered to the script as an argument

The ticket number structure needs to be as follows: `TICKET` + 7 digits, e.g., `TICKET1234567`.

The problem is that once the user types the ticket number, the regex is accepted only if I typed it manually, but if I copy and paste it from  notepad or any other text editor, the regex comparison fails with exit status of 1.

Note: if paste the ticket number and `echo $TICKET`, I see the correct ticket number.

Here is the function:

```
#helper to check TICKET  number structure
ticket_helper (){
    [[ $TICKET =~ '^TICKET[0-9]{7}$' ]]
    ES=$?
    if  [[  $ES -ne 0  ]];then
        echo  "Error:Please enter a valid TICKET number"
        exit 1
    fi
}

#requests user to enter TICKET number
read -p "Please Ticket Number "   TICKET
ticket_helper
```

How can I make the function accept the ticket number when pasting it from an editor?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the surrounding quotes from the pattern.

Replace :

`[[ $TICKET =~ '^TICKET[0-9]{7}$' ]]`

with :

`[[ $TICKET =~ ^TICKET[0-9]{7}$ ]]`

With quotes, the pattern is force to be matched as a string 
(from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is interpreted literally due to the single quotes. It is good practice to define it outside of your conditional operator in a variable.

It is also good practice to use lowercase variable names instead of uppercase ones, as they're less likely to clash with existing (environment) variables.

Instead of checking the exit status, you can use the conditional directly with a negation:

```
ticket_helper () {
    local re='^TICKET[0-9]{7}$'
    if [[ ! $ticket =~ $re ]]; then
        echo  "Error:Please enter a valid TICKET number"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: Hi All ,and thank you for your answer ,but  still I have the same problem while pasting ,i discovered that only if i am copying from snow (web based system)  to directly or after pasting it to text editor ,the regex is not excepted ,if i am typing directly to the terminal or typing to text editor and then paste it ,regex is accepted.

Comment: So, if you get the prompt to enter the ticket number, it only works if you type something directly, and you can't copy-paste the input? Might there be some invisible characters in what you're pasting? Can you try `cat -A <<< '`, then paste your word, then add the closing `'` so you have `cat -A <<< '[paste here]'`? This would show non-printable characters.